# Play audio and Redirect to page after some time

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on a project,I have to implement a functionality that on page load I have to play an audio file and while playing after some seconds redirect to some other page. I have used  tag and it's onplaying event,but its not working. Can any one suggest any alternative?Its not even hitting the function and showing no error in console
Below is my code

```
<embed src="contents/MP3/abc.mp3" height="0"
    width="0" autostart="TRUE" onplaying="return RedirecttoSite();"></embed>

    function RedirecttoSite() {              
            setTimeout(window.location.href = "/Default.aspx", 1000);
        }
```

What should be altenate solution to achieve this

Comment: I see you are adding audio to a web page. Allow me the time to turn and run, please.

Comment: You can tell any alternate solution

Comment: Firstly, telling why you'd want this would help in any possible alternate solutions.

Comment: as this is requirement of client

Comment: http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/JavaScript-Url-Redirect-with-Delay.aspx

Comment: I am also doing same :(

Comment: set timeout on body' load